# XPath to select value of an attribute using namespace

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

Hi I'm having a problem getting the value of an attribute in an xml file using namespaces.

```
<module name="ietf-inet-types"
        xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:yin:1"
        xmlns:inet="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-inet-types">
  <namespace uri="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-inet-types"/>
  <prefix value="inet"/>
</module>
```

I want to get "inet" as the result of my xpath. I used this link [Xpath to select value of sibling attribute with namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518096/xpath-to-select-value-of-sibling-attribute-with-namespace) as a reference and came up with:

```
$xml->xpath('/n:module/n:prefix/@n:value');
```

where n is the namespace prefix. However I'm getting an empty array as a result, what exactly am I doing wrong here?

Update:
Heres some of the php code I'm using to retrieve the value.

```
//gets the namespace from the model
$xpathNamespace = getXpathNamespace($domxml);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($domxml->saveXML());
$xml->registerXPathNamespace("n", $xpathNamespace);
print_r($xml->xpath('/n:module/n:prefix/@n:value'));
```

Answer (score 1):

In XML attributes without a namespace tag (eg. `value`) are not in any namespace: default namespace does not apply to attributes.

Try the XPath:

```
/n:module/n:prefix/@value
```

Comment: Hi I tried that but got the same result as when I use the xpath `/n:module/n:prefix/`.   The result is:                                                                                                                  `Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [value] => inet ) ) )`

Comment: @olliejjc16 In which case, could you update the question with the code you are using (specifically how you are associating `n` with the namespace in the XPath processor: but make it a complete but minimal re-create).

Comment: @olliejjc16 This might give some light : [Can I use SimpleXML & Xpath to directly select an Elements Attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045600/can-i-use-simplexml-xpath-to-directly-select-an-elements-attribute)

Comment: Thanks lads for the help, got it sorted between the information you both provided!

Answer (score 1):

Ok here's the solution thanks to both Richard and har07 combined for the help. To access the value of the prefix I used the below xpath suggested by Richard. From the information in the link posted by har7 I accessed the first element in the array and converted it to a string and I got the value "inet". Heres the code:

```
$prefix = $xml->xpath('/n:module/n:prefix/@value');
print_r((string)$prefix[0]);
```

Thanks to both for the help!